# How would I effectively use a lambda to iterate through an Iterable data structure and compare the values to local variables

Tags: java, foreach, iterable

Say `l1` is a data structure that implements `Iterable`, and `assertEquals()` was taken from JUnit 5.

I would like to assert that `l1` has the elements zero to 99 in order.
How can I do this with a lambda and forEach iterate through `l1`?

(The following code returns an error because `counter` is not final.)

```
int counter=0;
l1.forEach(t -> {
    assertEquals(counter,t);
    counter++;
});
```

Comment: Duplicate aside, you probably should _not_ be using `forEach` with a lambda if you want to just find out how many elements are in your collection.  Use the `size()` method instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would like to check that `l1` has zero to 99 in that order with a forEach and a lambda. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be a `forEach` and a lambda? Part of being a good programmer is to choose the correct tool for the task. `forEach` + lambda is the wrong tool for this task. A regular `for` loop will work just as well, better even, since it doesn't have the limitation the lambda does.

Comment: @Andreas I see, thank you. I'm new to Java, Iterators, and Lambdas, and I wanted to see what they could do. Is it possible, though?

Comment: Possible? Yes. But just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*. And you certainly shouldn't. Being new to Java, you should focus on doing it the right way, instead of trying to learn bad behaviors.